# inserting into ddbb without using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

To begin with this is my first time using JDBC.
I have a method called insertQuery and another one called updateQuery, both receive a String in order to update or insert a new movie in a db called Movies. So based on some values that the user will enter via a basic UI, my code will execute one query or the other one. The problem is that i'm getting a syntax error on the update and error 23000 on the insert and i don't know why

```
try {
  ResultSet rs = conn.selectQuery("SELECT title FROM movie WHERE title LIKE '" + title + "';");
  if (rs != null) {
    if (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println("Updating db...");
      conn.updateQuery("UPDATE movie SET title ='" + title 
                       + "', id_director = " + idDirector 
                       + ", year = " + year 
                       + ", duration = " + duration 
                       + ", country = '" + country 
                       + "', movie_facebook_likes = " + facebookLikes  
                       + ", imdb_score = "+ imdbScore 
                       + ", gross = " + gross 
                       + ", budget = " + budget 
                       + " WHERE title LIKE '" + title + "';");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Inserting into db...");
      conn.insertQuery("INSERT INTO movie (title, id_director, year, duration,
                       country, movie_facebook_likes, imdb_score, gross, budget) " +
                       "VALUES ('" + title + "', " + idDirector + "," + year + ", " 
                       + duration + ", " + country + ", " + facebookLikes + ", "
                       + ", " + imdbScore + ", " + gross + ", " + budget + ");");
    }
  }
} catch (SQLException e1) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainView, "MySQL error", "ERROR", .ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea not to use `PreparedStatement`. The stacktrace tells you details of the errors. Print the stacktrace with `e1.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: As above, be sure to read about SQL injection. If the stacktrace still leaves you puzzled and assuming the conn object is an instance a class you have defined, please share both the stacktrace and source of that class.

Comment: Please use prepared statements for this, concatenating values into a query string leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. When asking a question about an error, please post the full exception stacktrace in your question. The cause however seems to be missing quotes around `country` in your insert (the error is a 'relatively benign' form of SQL injection, and an indication that you really should be using prepared statements).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to i used to insert in db with no prepared statement:

```
public int adduser(String id, String nm, String pwd,String cy) {
    boolean result = false;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        Connection con=Util.getConnection();
        Statement stmt =con.createStatement();

        i = stmt.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO userdata (userid,name,password,city)\n" +
            "VALUES ("+id+",'"+nm+"','"+pwd+"','"+cy+"')");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return i ; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit and welcome to StackOverflow. I cleaned up the formatting slightly to make it more readable. While the main question was on how to not use prepared statements, which you answered, your code has potential SQL injection issues. I suggest you either add a warning or address this in your answer, as there's a risk that developers simply copy the answer and start using it in production code without realizing the issue.